# Gravitons from linearized gravity

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, carrier-particles, linearized-theory

Linearizing gravity as follows:

$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}
$$

Up to this point, everything is a 4x4 matrice.

How does one eventually recover a spin-2 particle which, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics), has for basis three 5x5 matrices?

Comment: An even better question is how does this lead to a *massless* spin-2 particle with 2, not 5, degrees of freedom.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263572/what-is-the-relation-between-the-metric-tensor-and-the-graviton), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108230/how-can-i-read-off-the-fact-that-gravity-is-associated-with-spin-2-particles-fro?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/374621/66086) may well be helpful.